# merge 2 data frames by 1:2 column ratio

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames

```
df1=data.frame(w=c(10,'a','a',14,''),data='other stuff')
df2=data.frame(c=10:14,n=letters[1:5],data='stuff')
> df1;df2
   w        data
1 10 other stuff
2  a other stuff
3  a other stuff
4 14 other stuff
5    other stuff
   c n  data
1 10 a stuff
2 11 b stuff
3 12 c stuff
4 13 d stuff
5 14 e stuff
```

I would like to make a final df that looks like (hand made):

```
10    stuff    other stuff
a     stuff    other stuff
a     stuff    other stuff
14    stfff    other stuff
      stuff    other stuff
```

I tried

```
merge(df1,df2,by.x='w',by.y='c|n')
```

to no avail, and am not sure how to solve this. Note that df1 and df2 are 1000s by 48 dimensions

Comment: What do you want the column names of the final dataframe to be? You seem to have a column with the same name in each of the separate dataframes.

Comment: the matching is from column w, and the values are not consistent. Some values are numeric, and others are char. I was hoping to merge it all in one go

Comment: Can you change values in data column into 1,2,3,... etc, so we can understand the expected output.

Comment: So, you want `df1` back with a new column added containing the value of `df2$data` appended which matches either `df2$c` or `df2$n` to `df1$w`? You will need to be careful with types. The way you have defined `df1` might be making `df1$w` a factor. See argument `stringsAsFactors` in `?data.frame`

Comment: for clarification,    df1$w holds a value that is in either column     df2$c or     df2$n, and I want to have the data columns from both df1 and df2 in the same data frame for manipulative purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can transform df2 to make one key column to match with df1 then use merge:

```
#dummy data updated data columns
df1 = data.frame(w = c(10,'a','a',14,''), data = paste('otherStuff', 1:5))
df2 = data.frame(c = 10:14, n = letters[1:5], data = paste('stuff', 1:5))

df1;df2

#    w         data
# 1 10 otherStuff 1
# 2  a otherStuff 2
# 3  a otherStuff 3
# 4 14 otherStuff 4
# 5    otherStuff 5

#    c n    data
# 1 10 a stuff 1
# 2 11 b stuff 2
# 3 12 c stuff 3
# 4 13 d stuff 4
# 5 14 e stuff 5


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

merge(df1,
      gather(df2, key = "Group", value = "w", -data),
      by = "w", all.x = TRUE)


#    w       data.x  data.y Group
# 1    otherStuff 5    <NA>  <NA>
# 2 10 otherStuff 1 stuff 1     c
# 3 14 otherStuff 4 stuff 5     c
# 4  a otherStuff 2 stuff 1     n
# 5  a otherStuff 3 stuff 1     n
```